# raw folder is not recognized even though it has been created in the "res" folder

Tags: android, media

[image: http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/7111/hlgy.png]

If I hover over the raw folder it says

"raw cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: try `project > clean`

Comment: When addressing a question, please use proper English.

Answer (score 9):

Well if its just a warning and everything seems to be working, then ignore it
If you can't read the values/data in Raw folder
then 2 options

> 1. clean your Project ( go to "project" menu and select clean)
> 2. Invalidate Caches /Restart Android Studio

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Try cleaning your project

> Project --> Clean...  then pick your project

Sometimes Eclipse doesn't pick up xml or resource changes right away so it throws these class cast exceptions. Simply cleaning and rebuilding the project usually takes care of such errors. Its a quick and easy thing to do before pulling out all of your hair trying to figure out why you would get such an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today.
Restarting android studio work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I put a music file in the raw folder in type ".m4a" and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the **R** was not imported properly.

Remove `import android.R` and import proper **R**.